# Check site certificates from Linux CLI over SSH

Tags: linux, certificate

Suppose that a website returns an invalid certificate, for which Firefox and Chrome give the user scary warnings. I would like to ensure that my local connection is not being man-in-the-middled (which is a real possibility in this case) so I would like to check the certificate from a remote server in another nation via SSH. How can this be done?

I did try simply opening the site in question with `elinks` but `elinks` apparently does not throw the same scary message for invalid certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First obtain the certificate using either `gnutls-cli` or `openssl s_client`.

```
gnutls-cli "$host" -p "$port" --insecure --print-cert < /dev/null > cert

openssl s_client -connect "$host:$port" -no_ign_eof < /dev/null > cert
```

Then dump all certificate information (usually lists at least two certificates, the server's and the CA's):

```
certtool -i < cert

while openssl x509 -text; do true; done < cert
```

Or just the SHA1 fingerprint of the topmost certificate:

```
certtool -i < cert | grep -A1 fingerprint

openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 < cert
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble with gnutls, so I [asked on unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62307/why-cant-gnutls-contact-this-site). I'll get back to your very detailed answer as soon as I've got the issues with gnutls sorted. Thank you Grawity!